# If Clu 2 had succeeded in escaping the Grid at the end of Tron Legacy. Would he appreciate art?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

Given that Clu2's primary function was "*to seek perfection*", is there any indication (from the film, script or other materials) that he has an appreciation of art? Would he just see it as a redundancy in the real world?

Comment: This is the most strangest question I've seen on this website lol.

Answer (score 4):

As we see in Tron Legacy, Clu2 is actually quite keen on art.

Not all art, obviously but certainly any art that consists of **500 ft high statues of himself**.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this have a function of a visual reminder of his presence?

Comment: @KINGOFCLUBS - I think an enormous poster would be more effective in that case. A statue (complete with ring) clearly has artistic merit.